# Can backend verify mobile client using OpenID Connect?

Tags: authentication, mobile, openid-connect

#### Objective

My goal is to implement a generic mobile client and backend authentication flow, just for practice. Imagine that I am building a note app that stores user notes on the backend. Instead of implementing my own user management in my backend, I want to rely on some popular OIDC providers to *authenticate* users from my backend.

The important thing is I am not interested in accessing any user data that OIDC Provider offers. My goal is to verify the user and the client whenever something hits my backend.

---

My understanding of OIDC Authentication flow is as follows:

- `IdProvider`: the oidc provider
- `MyClient`: mobile application. has `client_id`
- `MyBackend`: has `client_secret`

Steps:

1. `MyClient` generates PKCE code challenge.
2. `IdProvider` authenticates the user and `MyClient` receives a temporary `authorization_code`.
3. (not sure on this) `MyClient` sends `MyBackend` both the temp `authorization_code` and the PKCE code verifier for token exchange.
4. `MyBackend` does token exchange with the `IdProvider`.
5. (also not sure on this) `MyBackend` sends `id_token` and `refresh_token` back to `MyClient`.

---

My justification on step 3 and 5 are this:

- Only `MyBackend` can access `client_secret`. Therefore token exchange can only be done by `MyBackend` and `MyClient` is responsible for sending the temp `authorization_code` and the PKCE code verifier.
- `MyClient` needs `id_token` to hit normal `MyBackend` endpoints. `MyClient` also needs `refresh_token` to initiate the token refresh flow in case `id_token` expires.

---

#### Problem

Now in above flow it looks like there is no way I can prevent an attacker from stealing the `client_id` and impersonate `MyClient`. I have tried to search for sample implementation on the internet but many of them simply rely on the client-side authentication only. For example, this one: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoAuthDemo asks you to store `client_secret` in the client side.. I am not sure why this is acceptable and AWS even built a sample for it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the authorization code flow, the client credentials are only passed between the backend and IdProvider.
There is no need to pass Refresh and Id Token to the app. You may just keep them on the backend. Then you need to establish some sort of session for the app in the backend (maybe in the form of a traditional session id). This pattern is called backend for frontend.

As an alternative you may register your app as a public client (without a secret!). Using the authorization code flow the app gets the ID Token and relays it to the backend. The backend uses this as proof of identity.

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminH. I think I will follow your first suggestion. I am also looking into this Dynamic Client Registration to see if this is useful for client verification.

Comment: Dynamic Client Registration is for when you (as an IdP) don't know your clients. In your example I don't really see its necessity.

Comment: @BenjaminH, thank you for follow up. [This article](https://hackernoon.com/api-protection-requires-both-user-and-app-authentication-8a8101ed3f23) describes the problem I wanted to resolve very well. And I was trying to follow [another article](https://hackernoon.com/strengthening-oauth2-for-mobile-f4f3925dbf18) by the same author. The author mentions _Dynamic Client Authentication_, and I assumed he meant _Dynamic Client Registration_ because I couldn't find any further information when I searched for _Dynamic Client Authentication_